# W/GAV2 Exception sending hit: HttpHostConnectException

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

I'm using Samsung Galaxy Nexus Verizon (toro) w/ stock ROM, and I constantly see this in my logcat:

```
W/GAV2    (  903): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Exception sending hit: HttpHostConnectException
W/GAV2    (  903): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Connection to http://www.google-analytics.com refused
```

any ideas what this is? do I really need it? Can I disable it? is it eating more CPU(battery)?

Comment: GAV2 == Google Analytics V2